# Show "\n\r" in output By Doubling backlash

Tags: php, regex, newline

How i can Output `\n` OR `\r` OR `\n\r` IN Output of PHP Using "Regular Expression" ?

I know backlash should be double but I couldn't do it.

My Code

```
preg_replace('/(\n|\r)/', '?', $String );
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do? Output something? Replace something? What is `$H`? What do you want the result of `preg_replace` to be?

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't understand your question exactly. Is that you want to replace all \n and \r with '?' from your string $H.

Comment: Line separators are platform-independent. What platform are you on and why would you need to replace those ad-hoc? BTW windows line-separators are "\r\n" not "\n\r" ... mind the double quotes too.

Comment: i want to double backlash.. if in string \n used replace it with \\n to show "\n" in output for user.. if used \r replace with \\r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) - You don't need a regex:

```
$H = str_replace( "\n", '\n', $H);
$H = str_replace( "\r", '\r', $H);
```

Or as Mark points out, in one call:

```
$H = str_replace( array( "\n", "\r"), array( '\n', '\r'), $H);
```

Or, with two unnecessary regular expressions:

```
$H = preg_replace( "/\n/", '\n', $H);
$H = preg_replace( "/\r/", '\r', $H);
```

Or, one regular expression and some additional logic:

```
$H = preg_replace_callback( "/(\n|\r)/", function( $match) {
    return $match[1] == "\n" ? '\n' : '\r';
}, $H);
```

Comment: You don't even need to execute str_replace twice: $H = str_replace( array( "\n", "\r" ), array( '\n', '\r' ), $H);

Comment: Can i Replace it with preg_replace and not use str_replace ?

Comment: @nickb he should probably accept your final solution ... I think this post needs to change the title to 'regex masturbation'.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to output?

```
$H = "This is a line with \\n and \\r  and \\r\\n";
$H = "This is a line with " . '\n and ' . '\r and ' . '\r\n';
```

Or simply single-quote the entire string so php won't eval the escapes ...

```
$H = 'This is a line with \n and  \r and  \r\n';
```

You don't need a RegEx to output the literal '\n' '\r' or '\r\n'.

Just double back-slash the double-quoted string escapes or single-quote the string where you want to output the literals.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this might be what you are looking for...

```
$String = preg_replace('/\\n/', '\\n', $String ); 
echo preg_replace('/\\r/', '\\r', $String );
```